# Regex expression to split a line to three segments in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, concatenation

I am parsing a text file and I get multiple lines in the form shown below.

Then I try to split each line to three segments: Part1: sf; part2: name; part3:direction.

But now I am encountering difficulty in how to write my regular expression. I have thought about splitting on whitespace and using an array to concatenate new strings:

```
S15,F49  Large Recipe Download Request (LRDR)   S,H->E,reply

my ($sf, $name, $direction) =~ / I don't know how to implement here/
```

How can I get $sf = `S15,F49` // other lines like `S1,F11`; `S6,F1`; etc

$name = `Large Recipe Download Request (LRDR)` // different name for different $sf.

$direction = `S,H->E,reply;` // some time it is `M,H<-E,reply` or `S,H<->E` or `S,H->E,[reply]`, etc. There is no white space between each of sub items for part3: $direction

Comment: Format of the given line always remain the same:
S15,F49  Large Recipe Download Request (LRDR)   S,H->E,reply
like first part will contain comma(,) or second part will contain round brackets() always?

Comment: @Nikhil. Yes, I just want to split the line to three segments and generate a XML file based on the output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is no whitespace within the `$sf` and the `$direction` items, then you could apply the following code to each line:

```
if ($subject =~ m/^(\S+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\S+)$/) {
    $sf = $1;
    $name = $2;
    $direction = $3;
} else {
    // no match found
}
```

**Explanation:**

`^`: Anchor the regex at the start of the string.

`(\S+)`: Match one or more non-space characters. Capture the match in `$1`.

`\s+`: Match one or more space characters (= separator(s) to the next item).

`(.*?)`: Match any number of characters, as few as possible to still allow the overall match to succeed, and capture that in `$2`.*

`\s+(\S+)`: Similar to the above - match space separator(s) and non-space characters --> `$3`.

`$`: Anchor the search at the end of the string.

---

*The reason for the lazy quantifier `*?` is that otherwise, this part of the regex would also capture all the following space separators except the last one.

Comment: At first I was curious whether this would work because of the non-greedyness of the second group. But since the last group requires at least one character it works fine. If the second group were greedy, I think it could be a tiny teeny little bit faster because it should backtrack less frequently but I'm not 100% sure. Of course this would be a micro optimization but we don't know how often this code gets called.

Comment: I don't think it's going to make much of a difference as for performance. However, the match results will be different, depending on whether I use a lazy or a greedy quantifier (see my edit at the bottom).

Answer (score 2):

```
my $str = "S15,F49  Large Recipe Download Request (LRDR)   S,H->E,reply";

$str =~ /^([^\s]+)   # sf: anything except whitespace until first whitespace
           \s+
           (.+)      # name: anything 
           \s+
           ([^\s]+)$ # direction: anything except whitespace, from last
                     # whitespace to the end
        /x;
my ($sf, $name, $direction) = ($1, $2, $3);
print $sf, "\n", $name, "\n", $direction, "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you show, this should work:

```
my ( $sf, $name, $direction ) = split /\s{2,}/, $line;
```

Split by more two or more spaces.

This will auto-chomp:

```
my ( $sf, $name, $direction ) = split /\s{2,}|\n/, $line;
```

Comment: I failed to implement with your split method.

Please see the link for more details.

http://codepad.org/8n5b8pAd

Show warning on my laptop (ActivePerl 5.10 used): Use of uninitialized value $direction in concatenation (.) or string at D:\learning\perl\nextLine.pl line 24, <DATA> line 3.
direction =

Comment: On the paste site, you have a single tab. between the name and direction. So I would changed the regex to read `/\s{2,}|\t|\n/` and got what I needed. Up in your example, you had 3 spaces.